# How to fix these two Docker warnings on CentOS 8

Tags: docker, centos, centos8

How to fix these two warnings

```
WARNING: No blkio weight support
WARNING: No blkio weight_device support
```

**docker version**

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.1
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        831ebea
 Built:             Tue Dec 15 04:34:30 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.1
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       f001486
  Built:            Tue Dec 15 04:32:21 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.3
  GitCommit:        269548fa27e0089a8b8278fc4fc781d7f65a939b
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc92
  GitCommit:        ff819c7e9184c13b7c2607fe6c30ae19403a7aff
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

**docker info**

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  buildx: Build with BuildKit (Docker Inc., v0.5.0-docker)

Server:
 Containers: 5
  Running: 5
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 5
 Server Version: 20.10.1
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: xfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc io.containerd.runc.v2
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 269548fa27e0089a8b8278fc4fc781d7f65a939b
 runc version: ff819c7e9184c13b7c2607fe6c30ae19403a7aff
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
  userns
 Kernel Version: 4.18.0-240.1.1.el8_3.x86_64
 Operating System: CentOS Linux 8
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 8
 Total Memory: 7.559GiB
 Name: V-app-push2021
 ID: UXSD:UFLJ:JJTA:RFIC:PMCO:IPA2:MDZB:6NXD:2IGP:OZFK:5WEJ:2HPH
 Docker Root Dir: /data/lib/docker/1000.1000
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Registry Mirrors:
  https://hub-mirror.c.163.com/
  https://dockerhub.azk8s.cn/
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No blkio weight support
WARNING: No blkio weight_device support
```

Comment: Facing same problem with mint

Comment: Did u fixed it?

Comment: How you've solved this? Please let us know or put you solution so we all can find useful / will get your help.